# Apacheでmod_Rewriteなどを使い、違うサーバに行くはずのリクエストを内部で処理したい。

Tags: apache

CentOS+Apacheで以下のドメインを設定しています。

Server1のvirtualhost
`http://www.test.com/

https://new-sslhost.com/`

Server2のvirtualost
`https://sslhost.com`

---

現在以下のindex.htmlの中には以下のような記述があります。
`http://www.test.com/index.html`
`<a href="https://sslhost.com/"><img src=https://sslhost.com/image.jpg></a>`

---

これをApacheのmod_Rewriteなどを使い
`http://test.com/index.html`を表示した時に
「img src=`https://sslhost.com/image.jpg`」を「img src=`https://new-sslhost.com/image.jpg`」に書き換えたい。
リンクをクリックした時にアドレスバーは`https://sslhost.com`を表示しながら、
実際は`https://new-sslhost.com`を表示させる事は可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

> リンクをクリックした時にアドレスバーはhttps://sslhost.comを表示しながら、
>   実際はhttps://new-sslhost.comを表示させる事は可能でしょうか。

アドレスバーに `https://sslhost.com` と表示される場合、ブラウザはServer2に直接アクセスするわけですから、無関係なServer1でどうこうすることはできません。そんなことが容易にできては、フィッシング詐欺に使われてしまうでしょう。

もちろんServer1以外に手を加えれば、そのようなことも可能です。

- クライアントのhostsファイルに `https://sslhost.com` を記載する
- `https://sslhsot.com` 宛をServer1に送るプロキシを作り、クライアントに設定する
- 自分宛のアクセスをServer1に送るリバースプロキシをServer2に設定する

いずれの方法も、正規の通信経路上で改変を行うというのがポイントです。

> `http://test.com/index.html`を表示した時に「img src=`https://sslhost.com/image.jpg`」を「img src=`https://new-sslhost.com/image.jpg`」に書き換えたい。

これは可能です。が、mod_rewrite はリクエストのURLを内部的に書き換えるモジュールに過ぎず、レスポンスの中身を改変する機能は持ちません。代わりに mod_substitute が使えるのではないでしょうか。

[本番環境と開発環境の差を mod_substitute で吸収する - PSI Labs](http://www.psi-net.co.jp/blog/?p=874)